# updating my table with prepare command increase the value by 2

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepare

I am trying to run this simple mysqli command in php:

```
$query = "UPDATE config SET visit = visit + 1";
if ($stmt = $con->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Table config only has 1 row. However, the value instead of 1, it is increasing by 2!

So if the current value is 0, the next value will be 2, and then 4, etc!

I cannot understand this.

Comment: Other combinations like visit=visit+? , etc has the same result :(

Comment: Did you use any URL routing for this?

Comment: This is a simple mysqli command. What is URL routing, and what it has with this issue?

Comment: It works fine with phpmyadmin when I run it there. But running alone in my php case it to increase the visit value by 2

Comment: well this thing happened with me browser sends a .ico request also along with / . So because i routed all my requests to index.php file for a single request it was being evaluated twice.Better check the access log files for it

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I added a favicon.ico and it solved the issue.

Comment: no problem happy to help you out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with prepared statements (by the way, you don't need one here) nor even with sql at all. It is your whole php script being executed twice, thanks to wrong implementation of SEO friendly urls. You have to always verify if you're processing a valid request. And never run any SQL for invalid ones.

PS. Add favicon.ico for your site.

I'll take a liberty to stress on it again. It is not favicon.ico to blame, **but wrong implementation of SEO friendly urls.** There will be hundreds other requests that should result in 404 response, not views increment. You have to cure the disease, not one of symptoms. You have to fix your entry point that sh**ould not process requests to image files at whole**.